# How To Pass data From Intent To Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

i am new at kotlin, and i want to send data from my activity to my tabbed fragment, so after the user data, i want to show user-related followers and following using Tabbed Fragment at the same activity, so i created 2 fragments, and try to send the ArrayList to both fragments

```
    val listdata: Account? =intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_DATAS)
        if (listdata != null) {
                name.text = listdata.name
                username.text = listdata.username
                company.text = "${listdata.company} , ${listdata.location}"
                repository.text = "${listdata.repository}  total repo"
                following.text = "${listdata.following} following"
                followers.text = "${listdata. followers}  followers"

                this.title = listdata.username
             url_followers = "https://api.github.com/users/${listdata.username}/followers"
             url_followings = "https://api.github.com/users/${listdata.username}/following"

            Glide.with(this)
                .load(listdata.avatar)
                .into(imgPhoto)

        }
        ShowViewPager()
        getData(url_followers) //this return arraylist
        getData(url_followings) //this return arraylist

        val fragment = FollowersFragment.newInstance(getData(url_followers))
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("HaloHalo","coba")
        val fragfollowers = FollowersFragment()
        fragfollowers.setArguments(bundle);
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(FollowersFragment(),"hihi").commit()

//        val bundle2 = Bundle()
//        bundle2.putParcelableArrayList(FollowingFragment.EXTRA_DATA,getData(url_followings))
//        val transaction2 = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
//        val fragfollowers2 = FollowingFragment()
//        fragfollowers2.arguments = bundle2
//        transaction2.commit()
```

and this is how i get the data,but it didn't show any of them, just null
this is my companion object in FollowersFragment

```
companion object {
        private var list: ArrayList<Account> = arrayListOf()
        fun newInstance(data: ArrayList<Account>)= FollowersFragment().apply  {
            val fragment = FollowersFragment()
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putString("punten", "coba coba")
            fragment.setArguments(args)
            return fragment
        }


    }
```

and this is onCreateView function in my followersFragment

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_followers, container, false)

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        var sect : TextView = rootview.findViewById(R.id.section_label_followers)
//        list = this.getParcelableArrayList<Account>(EXTRA_DATA)
//        val test = arguments
        var bundle = arguments
        var cak = bundle?.getString("hihi")
        var cek = bundle?.getString("punten")

        sect.text = cak + cek
        return rootview
    }
```

when i tried arraylist and failed i thought that that problem caused by my empty araylist, but after i tried using string like code above, it still not sending any of them, can you help me with this?

i use pageadapter, this is my page

```
private fun ShowViewPager() {
        val sectionsPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(this)
        val viewPager: ViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewPager)
        viewPager.adapter = sectionsPagerAdapter
        val tabs: TabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout)
        TabLayoutMediator(tabs, viewPager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = resources.getString(TAB_TITLES[position])
        }.attach()
        supportActionBar?.elevation = 0f
        
    }
```

Comment: so your fragment is on viewpager and your viewpager is attached with activity right??

Comment: @D_K yes, but i cant figured it out how to pass the data

Answer (score 0):

see first in your Activity file create one function to pass data to the pager adapter like this :

```
DialPadPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new DialPadPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE, tabList, contactsArrayList);

pagerAdapter.refreshList(list,position);
```

in your pagerAdapter class another refreshList() to pass data to the fragments

```
public void refreshList(ArrayList<CallogsList> list, int position) {
        contactArrayList = list;

        if (position == 0) {
            Fragment1.refreshList(contactArrayList);
        } else if (position == 1) {
            Fragment2.refreshList(contactArrayList);
        }
    }
```

And in your fragment (same for the both fragments)

```
 public static void refreshList(ArrayList<CallogsList> list) {
       // your adapter to send the arraylist
        adapter.refreshList(list);
        
    }
```

In adapter class add this function

```
 public void refreshList(ArrayList<CallogsList> list) {
        yourList = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: so first i have to send the data to pageradapter right?, but i still cant find the way to write the DialPadPagerAdapter in kotlin,

Comment: create new kotlin and add this code editor will handle it by itself and convertt it to kotlin automatically

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass Data to Adapter via constructor -> Pass Data to NewInstance Fragment. I have tried and succeeded.

Follow Code Snippet:

Adapter:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity, private val listData: ArrayList<Int>) :
FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {
override fun getItemCount() = 2

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    when (position) {
        1 -> {
            return FragmentOne.newInstance(listData)
        }
    }
    return FragmentTwo.newInstance(listData)
}
```

}

Fragment:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
        val data  = it.getIntegerArrayList("Key")
        Log.e("Namlxcntt", " Fragment Two -> ${data?.toArray()} ")
    }
}
companion object {

    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(listData: ArrayList<Int>) =
        FragmentTwo().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putIntegerArrayList("Key", listData)
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: hey, it would be great to add a code snippet for the OP to understand.